# tensorflow Variable error: shape error even though shape is ok

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

hi i've been trying to make a RL program for blackjack.
i made all code with Q-network and it works.
however my new code with DQN has an error which is about shape.

```
X=tf.placeholder(shape=[1,state_number],dtype=tf.float32)
W1=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([state_number,128],0,0.01))#network for update
layer1=tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(X,W1))
```

this is a graph and running code for this is below

```
Qs=sess.run(Qpred,feed_dict={X:one_hot(s)}
```

i check the shape of one_hot(s) by this code and the result is below

```
print(np.shape(one_hot(s)))
(1, 600)
```

the error code is like this.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed 
a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [1,600]
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1,600], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

in the Q-network code, it works. idk why it suddenly doesnt work this time.
plz help me out. thanks

Comment: 1. What is `Qpred`?
2. Where do you provide the `state_number`?

Comment: Are you sure the output of `one_hot` is a float? Might be a type issue.

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the code that the variable `state_number` is equal to 600. I also guess that the values returned from  `one_hot()` function are integers (which would be something common).
If all of that is true, try casting the output of `one_hot()` to float32:

```
X = tf.placeholder(shape=[1,state_number],dtype=tf.float32)
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([state_number,128],0,0.01))#network for update
layer1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(X,W1))
```

and then:

```
Qs = sess.run(Qpred,feed_dict={X:one_hot(s).astype(np.float32)} )
```

Comment: thanks for answering. yeah state_number is 600. i tried what u told me but it still makes the same error. i have a code without DQN but for Q-network. and the main code for tensorflow is almost the same.. idk why it the error comes up :(

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the placeholder rising the exception is X? try to rename the placeholder (i.e. `X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,state_number], name='input_data')`) and run the code again. If it is this placeholder to raise the exception then you should see 'input_data' instead of 'Placeholder' in the error message. In the opposite case, be sure you are feeding each placeholder with a value inside feed_dict.

Comment: i did it and the error message is like this.tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_data' with dtype float and shape [1,600]
  [[Node: input_data = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1,600], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Comment: and i printed the shape and the input. (1, 600)
[[0. 0. 0................. 0. 0.]] . it seems like its [1,600] shape and float32...

Comment: Are you sure you are not reassigning the variable X? try feeding the one hot vector by calling the variable name rather than directly X: i.e. use `Qs = sess.run(Qpred,feed_dict={'input_data:0' : one_hot(s).astype(np.float32)} )`

Comment: dang i use X twice.. i should've assign X and X1.. thanks bro.

Comment: You are welcome :) it can happen... If you think you could upvote my answer I would get some points for it and I would really appreciate it! Thanks and bye ;)